# How Do I Test A Camel Route That Reads From A Directory?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I am creating a Camel application that reads files dropped into a directory on an FTP server, converts them and uploads to a REST API.

If I create a route that reads a file like this:

```
    from("file://target/input?delay=5s")
      .choice()
      .when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith(".xml"))
        .unmarshal(jaxb)
```

The `target/input` directory has to exist which then makes testing a bit awkward as my test resources might not be in the correct directory.

In my test it would be easier to just get the contents of the test file and put it into the unmarshal part of the route

```
    from("direct:xml")
      .unmarshal(jaxb)
```

How do I make my Route flexible enough to test without just copying the whole route to a test class and modifying the input component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply **make your `from` endpoint configurable** and configure it through **application properties**.

For example if you use Spring:

```
@Value("${endpoint.consumer}")
private String consumerEndpoint;
...
from(consumerEndpoint)
...
```

You can then provide a **test configuration** that configures the endpoint as `direct:input` and use a `ProducerTemplate` to send test messages with different payloads to this endpoint.

Real application properties:

```
endpoint.consumer=file://target/input?delay=5s
```

Test properties:

```
endpoint.consumer=direct:input
```

Like this you get rid of any file endpoints in your tests.

If you also got `to` endpoints, you can make them configurable too. You can turn them into mocks in your tests by configure them as `mock:whatever`.

Comment: Can you give an example of making it configurable through application properties.

Comment: i have extended my answer

Comment: Thanks. I thought at first there was some special Camel configuration properties!